# Titanium Studio : Error loading Android SDK

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have installed Titanium Studio and it works fine with iOS SDK. I have also downloaded Android SDKs and configured the same in Titanium Studio. However it shows me "Internal error occurred while loading Android SDK.". I don't know how to figure out the issue and unable to find any appropriate solution on Google. Screenshots for both error and SDK installation is attached.

Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.3.201404181442

[image: SDK Manager]
[image: Error Page]

Comment: didi the same error occurs when you run from command line?

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Sorry buddy I don't know what I did but I am not using Titanium :). By the way I think my colleague installed correct SDK and it is solved.